# Como usar promise.all() en async/await?

Tags: javascript, promesas, fetch, async-await

Me gustaría utilizar `Promise.all` en el siguiente código
para que se ejecute cuando se haya obtenido una respuesta de las promesas `getUsers` y `getTodos`.

¿Pueden darme un ejemplo de cómo implementarlo?

```js
async function getData() {
  try {
    let getUsers = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    let getTodos = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
    let users = await getUsers.json();
    let todos = await getTodos.json();
    let user = users.map(item => item.name);
    let todo = todos.map(item => item.title);
    console.log(user);
    console.log(todo);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ' + error);
  }
};
getData();
```

Answer (score 6):

Lo que hace [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all) es esperar a todas las promesas dentro de un array, es importante recalcar que en el momento en que una de todas las promesas del array falle, todo el `Promise.all()` lo hará y no vas a tener acceso a tus datos.

Yo haría esto:

1. Encapsulo la función que obtiene los datos y les hace el parse (`.json()`).
2. Utilizo un array con las funciones encapsuladas para utilizar con `Promise.all()`
3. Utilizo el `await` haciendo una [destructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment) sobre el array para obtener los resultados.

```js
const fetcher = async(path) => {
  let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' + path);
  return await response.json()
}

async function getData() {
  try {
    let [users, todos] = await Promise.all([fetcher('/users'), fetcher('/todos')]);

    let user = users.map(item => item.name);
    let todo = todos.map(item => item.title);
    console.log(user);
    console.log(todo);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ' + error);
  }
};
getData();
```